# Como subir mi archivo php a un hosting

Tags: php, xampp, hosting

Hola tengo una consulta he realizado una pagina en php(es mi primera página), por el momento todo esta en  un localhost ahora que ya tengo un hosting, **como podría hacer para subirlo?** **cuales serían los pasos a seguir?**
yo normalmente llamo el archivo **localhost/mi_archivo/index.php**   y se habré por que yo tengo el XAMPP en mi computadora pero ahora el hosting lo voy a manejar desde una laptop la cual no tiene instalado el XAMPP.

**¿Es necesario instalar el XAMP en esa laptop?**

Agradecería enormemente su apoyo.

Comment: es un hosting contratado o estas hablando de pasar tu proyecto simplemente a otra pc?

Comment: es un hosting contratado y lo tiene otra persona yo le brindare el programa en php

Comment: Spongo es una *shared hosting* entonces investiga sobre el uso de **filezilla** con dicho software lograrás subir tu página

Comment: entonces no es necesario que instale el xampp en la laptop de la otra persona?

Comment: Si lo que vas a usar para almacenar es un hosting contratado, entonces no veo la necesidad de instalar XAMPP en otra PC, salvo que tengas pensado desarrollar también en la otra

Comment: gracias por tu apoyo @Aprendiz

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario instalar XAMP en tu Laptop. Solo debes de usar el FTP que te brinda tu proveedor de hosting; Para mayor comodidad puedes usar fileZilla para gestionar tu contendio hacia el host remoto.

Tambien las herramientas de desarrollo como DreamWeaver pueden subir tu proyecto directmaente al host remoto si configuras correctamente el FTP.

Comment: al usar el FTP tambien se podran enviar correos ?

Comment: para enviar correos tienes que activar el servidor smtp. Casi siempre viene incluido con el hosting, por ejemplo smtp.tudominio.com o pop3.tudominio.com.

crea una cuenta de correo con ellos y podras usarla para enviar correos en cualquier plataforma.

Si no te proveen este servicio puedes usar una cuenta de microsof.live SMTP que tambien permite hacerlo, por ejemplo con tu correo de outlook.

FTP solo es para subir archivos(File Transfer Protocol).
SMTP es para enviar correos(Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) casi siempre ya esta configurado en tu host.